# Company raised starting offer, how to ask HR for my corresponding hike?

Tags: raise

I have been working in a fairly large IT company since past ~4 years. Two years after I joined the company, the company raised the starting offer significantly and it was further raised this last year, so much that a brand new employee who has just graduated college is probably earning more than me. I have already talked to my manager about this and he suggested me to meet the HR since they decide the compensation. I am planning to meet the HR regarding this. How do I breach the subject? Should I start off by saying that I am being underpaid? Should I share online links from websites like glassdoor? I had a couple of offers last year which offered around ~20% hike from my current salary but I couldn't join due to personal reasons. Should I bring that up at all or will I get fired for that?

Thanks

Edit: Included the fact that I have already talked to my boss about it.

Comment: see: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/668)

Comment: @Mark Rogers - I actually did take a look at that but I have already approached my boss and he was the one who suggested me to talk to HR since apparently they're the ones who decide the amount. I also think my case is slightly different since this is a company wide issue with people who started before the company decided to hike the starting offers. For instance one of my peers who started an year after me is making about 13% more than me. My average hike has been ~5% over past 3 years.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - I've had ~5% raise on an average over past 3 years but I am still being underpaid.

Comment: Talking to a friend revealed that his raises were in 6.5-8% range.

Comment: In  a high demand field starting offers can exceed existing salaries.  Don't bring up another offer unless you have signed  offer in hand and are ready to leave.   If the 20% raise as stable as what you have.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If you are like an HTML5 or mobile app person and started low then 5% could be low.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/how-do-i-renegotiate-my-salary-when-new-hires-start-in-higher-ranges/1733#1733

Comment: Would it matter if the fact that the starting salary increases were due to a general increase of the salary of your field, or due to an inability to bring in new hires? If there are unfilled openings the company is trying vainly to fill, the starting salary offered would be (perhaps temporarily) higher than what is "normal" for your field. You aren't underpaid, you're just already in a position with the company that they would not be able to fill if you weren't there. However, if the salary range of your field is moving up higher than your yearly increases, you are underpaid.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I broach the subject? Should I start off by saying that I am
>   being underpaid?

It would seem reasonable to indicate that you believe you are being underpaid and why. But it might be better to focus on your increased value to the company, rather than your salary relative to others. If the company decreased their starting offers, would you feel overpaid and ask for a reduction?

> Should I share online links from websites like glassdoor?

You could. But it would be unlikely that an HR group doesn't already know what is contained in those sites. It's their job to know this stuff. Most HR groups I know periodically purchase a lot of information on competitive salaries and salary trends for their industry and locale.

> I had a couple of offers last year which offered around ~20% hike from
>   my current salary but I couldn't join due to personal reasons. Should
>   I bring that up at all or will I get fired for that?

You could threaten to leave and indicate that you have had a couple of offers. Of course that fact that you didn't actually accept the offers (for whatever reasons), makes this a weaker excuse that you'd prefer.

You could be fired, although that would be unlikely.

Are you willing to walk out if you continue to be paid less than you feel is fair? If so, then you have some leverage. But if not, then there isn't much leverage in your favor. Just because it takes a higher offer to lure new graduates to your company - that doesn't automatically mean you are worth more to the company.

Remember, the company already knows how much you are being paid. And the company already knows how much they are offering others. So showing HR a bunch of facts and figures probably isn't going to sway their opinion.

Your displeasure might sway them. More importantly, demonstrating your worth to the company (without regard to how much others are paid) might hold more sway. It probably won't get you fired, and might be worth a try.

Comment: To be fair, I believe that I can get stuff done faster than a new graduate so I don't think if company reduced their starting offers I should get a reduction. As far as demonstrating my worth to the company goes I have already talked to my boss if I can do something differently or take more responsibility but his answer was no. Walking out is definitely on the cards but I don't want to get fired without having an offer in hand.

Comment: Probably not but he could have just shot it down instead of suggesting me to speak to HR.